# Friedman's long finite sequences-an unclear step in the proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, solution-verification, integers

I would like to understand [here](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/LongFinSeq98-2f0wmq3.pdf) on page $11$ in the proof of LEMMA $3.2.$ why

> sinc $k<b/3$ the only block of $b$ consecutive $3$'s are $b_{q+1}$ and (perhaps) $3^s$

I.e. **how** $k<b/3$ has been used there ? I'm skipping to $11$ page of a (moderately) technical paper
since I'm reading it carefully as it is interesting with the hope that someone else find it interesting too to read it up to that point.

Comment: Presumably "sinc" is a typo for "since" ?

Comment: @kimchilover It is a typo for since but still I do not know how to use $k<b/3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is really being used, so far as I can see, is that $k<b$. We know that $yB_pC_pB_{p+1}z$ contains two blocks of $b$ consecutive $3$s, one in $B_p$ and one in $B_{p+1}$, so $3^rC_qB_{q+1}C_{q+1}3^sw$ must also contain two such blocks. $B_{q+1}$ contains one of them. From the top of page $10$ we know that each of $C_q$ and $C_{q+1}$ contains exactly $k$ $3$s, and $k<b$, so neither $C_q$ nor $C_{q+1}$ contains a block of $b$ consecutive $3$s. Thus, the only possible locations for the other block are $3^r$ and $3^s$. However, clause (i) of the definition of type $2$ sequences requires that $r<b$, so $3^s$ is actually the only possible place of the other block of $b$ consecutive $3$s, and therefore we must have $s=b$, matching $B_{p+1}$. This implies that $B_p=B_{q+1}$ and hence that $p=q+1$, and also that $y=3^rC_q=3^rC_{p-1}$. Finally, $y$ is a tail of $C_{p-1}$, so we must have $r=0$, but then $y=C_{p-1}$, contradicting the requirement in the definition of type $1$ subsequence that it be a **proper** tail of $C_{p-1}$.

Comment: @user122424: After $C_{q+1}$ the original sequence continues with $B_{q+2}C_{q+2}$, which begins with at most the $b$ $3$s in $B_{q+2}$, since $C_{q+2}$ begins with a $2$. Thus, $s\le b$. And $B_p=B_{q+1}$ implies that $p=q+1$ because ‘It is understood that that a block $B_i(x)$ or $C_i(x)$ consists not only of the sequence of $2$’s and $3$’s, but also its position in $x$’ (page $10$), and its position in $x$ is indicated by the subscript $i$. Thus, $B_p$ is not just any block of $b$ $3$s: it is the block in position $p$. Saying that it is equal to $B_{q+1}$ is saying not only that they ...

Comment: ... are the same sequence of $2$s and $3$s, but that they are in the same position, meaning that $p=q+1$. Finally, if $r$ were greater than $0$, then $y$ would include part of $B_{p-1}$, the stuff that immediately precedes $C_{p-1}$, and therefore would not be a tail of $C_{p-1}$. But by definition $y$ **is** a tail of $C_{p-1}$, so $r$ must be $0$.

Comment: Actually I got lost at the end  of your (helpful) reply which becomes a bit sloppy there. Why "we must have $s=b$": what if $s<b$ ? I believe to you that $s>b$ is really not possible. Also why $B_p=B_{q+1}$ implies $p=q+1$ ? Finally how have you derived $r=0$ from the fact that $y$ is a tail of $C_{p-1}$: do we know for some reasons that $y$ starts with $2$ ? I have somehow mouse slipped and deleted my OC.

Comment: @user122424: I answered your original comment: see my comment above.

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me also why $s\geq b$ to really have $s=b$ ? Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: @user122424: I don’t understand, I’m afraid; we don’t have $s\ge b$ specified anywhere, so far as I can see.

Comment: OK, but we need this from your answer: "we must have $s=b$ matching $B_{p+1}$". So we need 2 inequalities one of which you have proved. Now I would like to have the opposite one.

Comment: @user122424: No, we don’t need to prove separately that $s\ge b$; it follows from the fact, which has already been proved, that $3^s$ must include $B_{p+1}$.